# Highlight selected item from number picker when it will open second time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-number-picker

I have number picker and I am filling it with string array.

```
final String[] power = {"0.00", "0.25", "0.50", "0.75","1.00"};
npPowerSecond.setMinValue(0);
npPowerSecond.setMaxValue(power.length - 1);
npPowerSecond.setDisplayedValues(power);
```

I display values as above. When I open number picker it will show "0.00" as a selected value. Now I am selecting "0.50". Now When I will open number picker, it should display "0.50" as selected value.

Can you please help me? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
npPowerSecond.setValue(2);
```

use setvalue to set.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the last selected position of `NumberPicker` to `SharedPreferences`. After that, everytime you open `NumberPicker`, you should set the default selected position for it by use [void setValue (int value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setValue(int))

```
final String[] power = { "0.00", "0.25", "0.50", "0.75s", "1.00s" };
NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(power.length - 1);
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(power);
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        // any time your number picker change, we will save it to SharedPreferences
        saveIntToSharedPreferences(mContext, PREF_NUMBER_PICKER_LAST_SELECTED_POSITION, newVal);
    }
});
// when we open screen, we will select the last selected value by use setValue(...) 
numberPicker.setValue(
        getIntFromSharedPreferences(mContext, PREF_NUMBER_PICKER_LAST_SELECTED_POSITION));
```

Helper function for save/get integer from `SharedPreferences`

```
private void saveIntToSharedPreferences(Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

private int getIntFromSharedPreferences(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npPowerSecond.setValue(selectedNumber);
```

after selecting value, set value to that number picker. I think it will help you.